# Truffle not calling the function in past time

Tags: mocha.js, blockchain, solidity, chai, truffle

I was writing writing some unit testing code for my vesting smart contract in truffle, when I encountered a problem, I had a function which was getting time as one of its parameters so instead of providing it with a manual time I was calculating the time in real time and passing it as a parameter, then I was using a timeout function to delay the time for a while so when I call the function of smart contract the block.timestamp would have been greater then the time passed previously but that was not the case, instead after debugging I found out that the block.timestamp was stuck when the contract was basically deployed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the delay or timeout functions, the problem is actually with truffle,it was solved when I used ganache network, for my unit testing.